# how to enable text compression for flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, lighthouse

I'm running a blank web project template:

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
flutter create myapp
cd myapp
flutter build web
flutter run --release
```

The lighthouse score out of the box is pretty catastrophic. And this is on a high-end PC:
[image: lighthouse performance score]

I guess improving this will be a complex long-term effort. But one metric in particular stands out to me: The release deployment is not compressing javascript. Is it possible to fix that?

[image: missing text compression]

Comment: text compression is server side not part of your project code. You would add the relevant instructions to your `.htaccess`, `nginx.conf` or in `IIS` and all files that you ask to be gzipped will then be compressed. I never bothered setting up for localhost as it is best to test speed on a real server but I am sure that is straight forward. What I don't get is how "main.dart.js" could be compressed to one tenth the size, that looks like an error in Lighthouse when it runs the compression test.